# Auto height increase when the mouse hover the navigation

Tags: html, css

I've created a drop-down navigation with CSS only.
If I hover the button and the submenu comes out.
But then the body will be higher. 
I don't want that the body will be higher.
Here the files:
http://jsfiddle.net/UHQV5/
I think the `position: relative;` is false.

Comment: You would need to use absolute position on the sub-menu(s).

Comment: @Paulie_D When a use the absolute position on the sub-menus, they not there. They vanished.

Comment: If they vanished, it's probably because you didn't specify how far off absolute you want and what direction (top: 20px; left: 20px; for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one?

added this:

```
nav ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

and removed some unnecessary ones.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UHQV5/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Nice looking website,

I messed with the code just a little and found the making the  tag have a id for the css. Then in the css setting the postion to fixed!

The Code:

From this

```
<nav>
<ul id="navigation">
         <li><a href="index.php?Startseite" class="first">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Bücher...&raquo;</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">für kleine Leser</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">für große Leser</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Schulbücher</a></li>
         </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">und mehr...&raquo;</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Filme</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ebooks</a></li>
         </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#" class="last">Seit 1851&raquo;</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Firmenhistory</a></li>
         </ul></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
```

To This

```
<nav id="nav">
<ul id="navigation">
         <li><a href="index.php?Startseite" class="first">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Bücher...&raquo;</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">für kleine Leser</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">für große Leser</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Schulbücher</a></li>
         </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#">und mehr...&raquo;</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Filme</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ebooks</a></li>
         </ul></li>
         <li><a href="#" class="last">Seit 1851&raquo;</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Firmenhistory</a></li>
         </ul></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
```

And then in the css just put in:

```
#nav {
     postion: fixed;
}
```

Comment: But than the navigation "follow" me down the page.